# Unable to copy folders from FTP site?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, ftp

I am using the code below which successfully gets the files in the presentation directory but not the folders. Is there a way to get the folder and its contents as well? Maybe in powershell this can be done instead of a batch file? When the code below runs I am getting an access denied on the folders but the files copy fine? Any ideas?

```
@Echo Off
Set _FTPServerName= 
Set _UserName=
Set _Password=
Set _LocalFolder= C:\Temp
Set _Filename=/Presentation
Set _ScriptFile=ftp1
:: Create script
>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo open %_FTPServerName%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo %_UserName%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo %_Password%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo lcd %_LocalFolder%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo binary
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo prompt
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo mget %_Filename%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo quit
:: Run script
ftp -s:"%_ScriptFile%"

pause
```

Comment: There are FTP client classes built into the .NET Framework which you can leverage from PowerShell. That would be much better than the method you're using presently.

Comment: Ya, I am just not familiar with Powershell. I have done very simple things in PS. Unless there is a very straight forward example?

Comment: If you do a few Google searches you'll find examples. You might even find some help under Related on the right-hand side here ->

Answer (score 0):

This may be of some help:

http://scriptolog.blogspot.com.au/2007/09/ftp-transfers-automation.html

You will need to register the DLL mentioned in the post.